# shifting a graph: graph starting from a different position

Tags: r, ggplot2, bioinformatics

I am using R to graph how many reads I got per nucleotide after a sequencing run. I have a Dataframe (depth_results) with two columns: position and depth. Position contains numbers from 1 to 4,625,919, which represents each nucleotide on an E. coli genome; depth contains a value that represents how many reads I have for that position.

I graph that data frame so in the x axis I have the genome positions and in the y axis, the depth.

```
ggplot(depth_results, aes(position, depth)) + geom_line()
```

The graph starts from position 1 till the end. I want to change that graph so it starts from a different position (the chromosome replication origin), which is located at position 3,923,804 and ends in 3,923,803. So it basically shifts to the right how the graph is plotted.

How can I do this? Is there a function in ggplot that allows me to do this?

Comment: You can set the axis limits to the values you want, in the case of the x axis, `xlim(start, end)`.

Comment: @Bawitdaba You could add a column which labels 1:3923803 as "A" and 3923804:4625919 as "B" then plot them as two different lines or even two different facets.

Comment: @Rui Barradas With xlim I can start from position 3,923,804 and go all the way to 4,625,919, but I don’t know how to make it to continue the graph from position 1 to 3,923,803

Comment: @Allan Cameron the issue is that I will be using the same data frame to add other conditions and it makes sense to  use them as different facets. An option that I was considering is just to rewrite the data frame starting from the position I want until the end and then just append the data from position 1 to the one I wanted; but I figured out that there should be a better solution than this.